# Passing param using link_to and UJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, parameter-passing, link-to

I'm having a hard time understanding the proper way to pass a param using link_to and UJS.

I have the following resources:

- Photos
- Comments
- Users

A user is trying to comment on a photo by clicking "Add Comment." When this happens a box pops up using UJS showing a form rendered by utilizing a new.js.erb file. After "Create Comment" is posted the create.js.erb file is called to handle the update, which just hides the comment box and adds the comment to a list of comments.

In my index.html.erb for my photos I am doing the following:

I specify a link to add comments passing in the id of the current photo.

```
<%= link_to 'Add Comment', new_comment_path( photo_id: photo.id ), remote: true %>
```

This gives me the url: 0.0.0.0:3000/comments/new?photo_id=1, which is what I expect.

Now my question is, how do I handle this passed parameter in my new action such that I can specify something like

```
@comment.photo_id = photo_id 
or 
@comment.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
```

in my comments_controller.rb?

Is there something I can do in JS that will help me save the photo_id value to my @comment.photo_id column for the comment added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'll suggest you to start using nested routes for things like comments or likes. You will find the railscast here [nested_routes_railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources)

Coming back to your question, use `@comment.photo_id = params[:photo_id]` in your controller.

---

There is a better approach to accomplish this, You can have the popup already on the photo show page. In the popup you can have a form for new comment model. After clicking on the specific photo you just have get the **id** of that photo using javascript and copy it into the hidden field for **:photo_id** in the form.

Comment: Let me if you need help in doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look into nested routes to see if it will work here. I was able to get it working using a hidden_field in my _form.html.erb shown via new.js.erb.

`<%= f.hidden_field :photo_id, { :value => params[:photo_id]} %>`

After this I could save the value in my create action in comments_controller.rb using `@comment.photo_id = params[:comment][:photo_id]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get photo_id in params, they way you have specified.
Suppose Photo has many comments in your case.
So in your case when in you get params[:photo_id] in comments_controller
you can do:-

```
@photo = Photo.find_by_id(params[:photo_id])
@photo.comments.create(params[:comment])
```

Please read about nested resources from guides.rubyonrails.org, so you can generate create comments route in restful manner.